# Checking a Column of Lists Against Another Column of Lists and Returning Multiple Column Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am comparing the list values of `sb_list` against `psr_list`. If all list items from `sb_list['ASINs']` are found in any of the lists from `psr_list['Child ASIN']`, `sb_list['bucket']` is marked `'clean'`. This part of the code is running fine...

What I am having trouble with is populating `sb_list['Group']`. If `['bucket']` is marked `'clean'` then `sb_list['Group']` should equal the corresponding `psr_list['Group']` where the match was found.

I am attempting to run the function to check each list of `sb_list['ASINs']` against `psr_list['Group']`, and return a tuple, with the first value of the tuple being clean/mixed for if a match was found, and the second value of the tuple being whatever `psr_list['Group']` value is for the matching row.

This is similar to another question I asked a few weeks ago, but different enough to where I thought it deserved its own post.

Data:

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = [
    ['1', ['hi', 'there', '10', '14', '15']],
    ['2',  ['7', '13', '25', '46', '50']],
    ['3',  ['hello', 'du', '6', '19', '36']],
    ['4',  ['hi', '19', '24', '26', '29']]]

psr_list = pd.DataFrame(list1, columns =['Group', 'Child ASIN']) 

list2 = [
    ['a', ['hi', 'there']],
    ['r',  ['hello', 'du', 'th']],
    ['e',  ['hello', '9']],
    ['f',  ['hello', '6', '36']],
    ['w',  ['hello', '6', '37']],
    ['a',  ['24', '29']],
    ['q',  ['hi', '14', '15']]]

sb_list = pd.DataFrame(list2, columns =['camp', 'ASINs']) 
sb_list['bucket'] = ""
sb_list['Group'] = ""
```

My attempt:

```
def process(psr_asin_list, sb_ap_asin_list):
  return [compare(psr_asin_list, sb_sp_row) for sb_sp_row in sb_ap_asin_list]

def compare(psr_asin_list, sb_sp_row):
  counter = 0
  while counter < psr_asin_list.shape[0]:
    if all(asins in psr_asin_list[counter] for asins in sb_sp_row): return ('clean', psr_asin_list['Group'])
    counter +=1
  return ('mixed', '')


sb_list['bucket'] = process(psr_list['Child ASIN'].to_numpy(), sb_list['ASINs'].to_numpy())[0]
sb_list['Group'] = process(psr_list['Child ASIN'].to_numpy(), sb_list['ASINs'].to_numpy())[1]
```

Desired output:

```
  camp            ASINs bucket Group
0    a      [hi, there]  clean     1
1    r  [hello, du, th]  mixed
2    e       [hello, 9]  mixed
3    f   [hello, 6, 36]  clean     3
4    w   [hello, 6, 37]  mixed
5    a         [24, 29]  clean     4
6    q     [hi, 14, 15]  clean     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `set.issubset` in a list comprehension to check if any list in `sb_list` is contained in any list in `psr_list`. If a list exists, then get "Group" value where it exists, if not fill in with `""`. Note that this assumes only one list in `psr_list` contains a list from `sb_list`.

Then fill in `bucket` depending on if a "Group" value was found or not:

```
def get_group(asin):
    group = psr_list.loc[[set(asin).issubset(y) for y in psr_list['Child ASIN'].tolist()], 'Group']
    return group.iat[0] if not group.empty else ''

sb_list['Group'] = sb_list['ASINs'].apply(get_group)
sb_list['bucket'] = np.where(sb_list['Group']=='', 'mixed', 'clean')
```

Output:

```
  camp            ASINs bucket Group
0    a      [hi, there]  clean     1
1    r  [hello, du, th]  mixed      
2    e       [hello, 9]  mixed      
3    f   [hello, 6, 36]  clean     3
4    w   [hello, 6, 37]  mixed      
5    a         [24, 29]  clean     4
6    q     [hi, 14, 15]  clean     1
```

Comment: You are calling the 'get_group' function without passing its one argument to it, yet it still works. How?

Comment: @anarchocaps because `psr_list` is already defined in your environment, so it’s a global variable for this function.

Comment: but 'asin' is the first arg when defining the function, but there is no arg used when calling the function, unless your answer is what you are referring to. I guess I am just not understanding how you can define a function with 1 arg, but call it using no args

Comment: @anarchocaps apply invokes `get_group` over every variable of the Series it’s called on, we could also use a lambda like: `.apply(lambda x: get_group(x))` but since we already have a function defined, we don’t need a lambda here (lambda is slow).

Comment: This makes sense. I am now attempting to pass 'psr_list' into 'get_group' by defining the function like this: 
 'get_group(asin, psr_list)', but this is not working. This is what prompted my comments above. How do I pass this additional arg in?

Comment: @anarchocaps you don’t need to pass in `psr_list`; it just overcomplicates things. But if you must, you can define `get_group` like the way you did and use apply like: `.apply(get_group, args = (psr_list,))`